# Synchronization mechanisms in distributed system

Tags: synchronization, distributed-system

What are the distributed synchronization mechanisms? Is it the answer can be physical clock and logical clock?

Comment: To give you a meaningful answer, we'd need to understand the context in which this question has arisen.

Comment: This is the exercise question given in my class. "What are the distributed synchronization mechanisms?" And the answers are i found myself on Internet. So, i just want to know the Synchronization mechanisms in distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're looking for [logical clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_clock).